# Cambiar grupo de permisos al crear o actualizar en Django

Tags: django, permisos

Un saludo a todos.

Tengo un sistema con el que creo 3 perfiles, docente, administrativo y servicios generales para un usuario.
A cada perfil corresponde un grupo de permisos.
Un usuario solo puede tener asignado un grupo de permisos a la vez.

Como puedo hacer que los grupos de permisos se asignen automáticamente?

Al crear un usuario con el perfil docente se asigne el grupo de permisos docente
Si actualizo este usuario con el perfil administrativo que se elimine el grupo de permisos del docente y que se asigne el grupo de permisos para administrativo.

```
class Empleado(MarcadorTiempo, Persona):
    usuario = models.OneToOneField(User, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='usuario', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_ingreso = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='fecha de ingreso')
    titulo_obtenido = models.ForeignKey(TituloObtenido, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='titulo obtenido',
                                        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    carrera_profesional = models.ForeignKey(CarrreraProfesional, null=True, blank=True,
                                            verbose_name='carrera profesional', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    perfil = models.ForeignKey(Perfil, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='perfil', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "empleado"
        verbose_name_plural = "empleados"
        ordering = ['usuario']

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.usuario.first_name, self.usuario.last_name)


class User(AbstractUser):
    foto_perfil = models.ImageField(upload_to='usuarios/perfil', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='foto de perfil')
    numero_documento = models.CharField(null=True, blank=False, verbose_name='numero de documento', max_length=40)
    celular = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='celular', max_length=40)
    codigo_verificacion = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='codigo de verificación', max_length=4)
    fecha_solicitud_codigo_verificacion = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True,
                                                               verbose_name='ultima fecha en que solicito el codigo')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('email',)
        verbose_name = "usuario"
        verbose_name_plural = "usuarios"
```

Comment: Tal como ya te respondieron, lo que necesitas es conocer el modelo de `Group`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yo cuando creo un usuario y quiero asignarle un grupo utilizo lo siguiente:

```
    usuario = User.objects.create_user(
            username=correo,
            email=correo,
            password="123"
        )
usuario.groups.add(Group.objects.get(name='grupo'))
```

No se si es lo que necesitas. Saludos